# How to present NEST query results?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to return NEST query results as console output.

My query is:

```
private static void PerformTermQuery(string query)
{
    var result = 
        client.Search<Post>(s => s
        .Query(p => p.Term(q => q.PostText, query)));
}
```

What I am getting is object, with 2 Documents. How to "unpack" it to show documents as json (full or partial) to the console?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using version 1.3.1 of NEST, you can:

- get raw JSON response using `result.RequestInformation.ResponseRaw.Utf8String()`
- parse JSON to get `_source`
- include/exclude `_source` properties using `SearchSourceDescriptor` on `SearchDescriptor`

  `var result = 
      client.Search<Post>(s => s
      .Query(p => p.Term(q => q.PostText, query)).Source(...));`

Comment: result.RequestInformation.ResponseRaw.Utf8String() is not available. Why?

Comment: [This method is internal](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Nest/Extensions/Extensions.cs). I was in NEST unit tests context when I was checking this. My fault. `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(...)` will do work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For NEST / Elasticsearch 5.x, `result.RequestInformation` is no longer available. Instead, you can access the raw request and response data by first **disabling direct streaming on the request:**

```
var results = elasticClient.Search<MyObject>(s => s
    .Index("myindex")
    .Query(q => q
        ...
    )
    .RequestConfiguration(rc => rc
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
    )
);
```

After you've disabled direct streaming, you can access **`results.ApiCall.ResponseBodyInBytes`** (if you look at this property without disabling direct streaming, it will be null)

```
string rawResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(results.ApiCall.ResponseBodyInBytes);
```

This probably has a performance impact so I would avoid using it on production. You can also disable direct streaming at the connection / client level, if you need to use it across all your queries. [Take a look at the documentation for more information](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-information.html).